# Query to find out advance search option

Tags: php

I have tried to find out searching from 3 fields. If I will fill only 1 field then data should search, if i will fill in 2 columns then data should search.
Help me out where i am wrong as data is searching from any scenario.

Below is my code which i have used but it not working :-

```
  $query = "";
$keyword = $_REQUEST['sports'];
$country = $_REQUEST['city'];
$category = $_REQUEST['code'];
if(isset($keyword)){//if keyword set goes here

   $query = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE sports LIKE '%$keyword%' OR postelcode LIKE '%$keyword%' OR city LIKE '%$keyword%'";

   if(isset($category)){
     $query = "AND postelcode LIKE '$category'";
   }
   if(isset($country)){
     $query  = "AND city LIKE '$country'";
   }
}else if (isset($category)){ //if keyword not set but category set then goes here
  $query = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE postelcode LIKE '$category'";
  if(isset($country)){
    $query  = "AND city LIKE '$country'";
  }
}else if(isset($country)){//if only country set goes here
  $query = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE city LIKE '$country'";
}


      $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) 
      {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
      {
      ?>     <ul>
                        <li>Contact Email :-   <?php echo $email;  ?></li>
                        <li>Sports        :-   <?php echo $row["sports"];  ?></li>
                    </ul>

                  <?php
        }
} 


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing `$query` variable value with each condition you are adding.

Use `.=` operator to append the new where clause to the previous query string.

Plus I have made some other changes which will make your code immune to errors by setting up isset to Request variable and replacing isset of where clause variables with !empty because you have already defined all the variables in the beginning of the code. So `isset()` will always be true.

```
$query = "";
$keyword = isset($_REQUEST['sports']) ? $_REQUEST['sports'] : '';   //Checking if parameter is passed
$country = isset($_REQUEST['city']) ? $_REQUEST['city'] : '' ;  //Checking if parameter is passed
$category = isset($_REQUEST['code']) ? $_REQUEST['code'] : '';  //Checking if parameter is passed
if(!empty($keyword)){//if keyword set goes here

   $query = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE sports LIKE '%$keyword%' OR postelcode LIKE '%$keyword%' OR city LIKE '%$keyword%'";

   if(!empty($category)){
     $query .= " AND postelcode LIKE '$category'";  // Added space before AND
   }
   if(!empty($country)){
     $query  .= " AND city LIKE '$country'";    // Added space before AND
   }
}else if (!empty($category)){ //if keyword not set but category set then goes here
  $query = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE postelcode LIKE '$category'";
  if(!empty($country)){
    $query  .= " AND city LIKE '$country'"; // Added space before AND
  }
}
if(isset($country)){//UPDATED THIS CONDITION: if only country set goes here
  $query = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE city LIKE '$country'";
}


      $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) 
      {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
      {
      ?>     <ul>
                        <li>Contact Email :-   <?php echo $email;  ?></li>
                        <li>Sports        :-   <?php echo $row["sports"];  ?></li>
                    </ul>

                  <?php
        }
}
```

Comment: I have used this code and works fine with one option but while searching only city or only postel code it is not working properly all data comes

Comment: Actually that is the another issue. To able to filter country, you should make the last condition separate `if` condition and not `else if`.
Please check my updated answer, and it should work for country search too. But keep in mind that $country is being checked with `city` column. So please confirm that too.

Answer (score 2):

`$query = "AND postelcode LIKE '$category'";` is logic which replaces your query. You need to append to it with `.=` if you're going to add conditions to the WHERE clause. Each instance of trying to add `AND` logic to your query needs to append to your select query, not replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the unneeded if blocks and improper string concatinations `(subsequent $query =".."; $query =".."; $query =".."; )` that just overwrite previous value of `$query`.

Use `.=` operator instead to combine strings - like - `$query = "text1 "; $query .= "text2 "; $query .= "text3";` - that results to - `$query = "text1 text2 text3";`

Also did proper initiation of variables (`$keyword, $country and $category`) to prevent notice errors. Also **mysqli_real_escape_string()** on the variables to prevent sql injection attacks.

The below code returns records that matches any of the search fields using mysql `OR condition`.

**Updated Code:**

```
$query = "";
$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, ((isset($_REQUEST['sports']) AND $_REQUEST['sports'] != "" )? "%{$_REQUEST['sports']}%" : ''));
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, ((isset($_REQUEST['city']) AND $_REQUEST['city'] != "" )? "%{$_REQUEST['city']}%" : ''));
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, ((isset($_REQUEST['code']) AND $_REQUEST['code'] != "" ) ? "%{$_REQUEST['code']}%" : ''));


if($keyword!="" OR $country!="" OR $category!=""){
   $query = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE sports LIKE '$keyword' OR postelcode LIKE '$category' OR city LIKE '$country'";

   $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
      ?>     
           <ul>
            <li>Contact Email :-   <?php echo $email;  ?></li>
            <li>Sports        :-   <?php echo $row["sports"];  ?></li>
           </ul>
       <?php
        }
    } 
}
```

The below code searches in all columns and returns records that match all search fields using mysql `AND condition`.

**Alternative Code:**

```
$query = "";
$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, ((isset($_REQUEST['sports']) AND $_REQUEST['sports'] != "" )? "%{$_REQUEST['sports']}%" : ''));
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, ((isset($_REQUEST['city']) AND $_REQUEST['city'] != "" )? "%{$_REQUEST['city']}%" : ''));
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, ((isset($_REQUEST['code']) AND $_REQUEST['code'] != "" ) ? "%{$_REQUEST['code']}%" : ''));


if($keyword!="" OR $country!="" OR $category!=""){
   $query = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE ";

   if($keyword!="") {
       $query .=  "sports LIKE '$keyword'";
   }

   if($category!="") {
       if($keyword!=""){
           $query .= " AND "
       }
       $query .= "postelcode LIKE '$category'";
   }

   if($county!="") {
        if($keyword!="" OR $category!="") {
            $query .= " AND "
        }
        $query .=  " city LIKE '$country'";
   }

   $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
      ?>     
           <ul>
            <li>Contact Email :-   <?php echo $email;  ?></li>
            <li>Sports        :-   <?php echo $row["sports"];  ?></li>
           </ul>
       <?php
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: If the above code works for you, you may wanna convert your `mysql queries` to use `prepared statements` as the preferred way to protect from `sql injection` attacks.